# If input value changed do something in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have 2 `input's` on my website, one is `type="number"` and second is `type="text"`.

I want to make script in **jQuery**, which will change value of my input (`text`) to value from first input (`number`).

What should I do?

Regards.

Comment: post some of your code, and the trigger function.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("change",".numfield",function(){
     $(".textfield").val($(this).val());
});
```

.numfield = the class (or id) of the number input field

.textfield = the class (or id) of the text input field